# Generalized Birthday Problem

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, probability-theory

Tonight, my fiancée took me out to dinner to celebrate my birthday. While we were out, I heard *Happy Birthday* sung to 5 different guests (including myself), in a restaurant full of 50 people. This got me wondering - the original birthday problem (finding the probability that 2 people in a room of `N` people share the same birthday) is very simple and straightforward. But what about calculating the probability that at least `k` people out of `N` people share the same birthday?

In case you're wondering, the probability of at least 5 people out of 50 total people sharing the same birthday is about 1/10000.

### The Challenge

Given two integers `N` and `k`, where `N >= k > 0`, output the probability that at least `k` people in a group of `N` people share the same birthday. To keep things simple, assume that there are always 365 possible birthdays, and that all days are equally likely.

For `k = 2`, this boils down to the original birthday problem, and the probability is `1 - P(365, N)/(365)**N` (where `P(n,k)` is [the number of k-length permutations formed from n elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n)). For larger values of `k`, [this Wolfram MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BirthdayProblem.html) may prove useful.

### Rules

- Output must be deterministic, and as accurate as possible for your chosen language. This means no Monte Carlo estimation or Poisson approximation.
- `N` and `k` will be no larger than the largest representable integer in your chosen language. If your chosen language has no hard maximum on integers (aside from memory constraints), then `N` and `k` may be arbitrarily large.
- Accuracy errors stemming from floating-point inaccuracies may be ignored - your solution should assume perfectly-accurate, infinite-precision floats.

### Test Cases

Format: `k, N -> exact fraction (float approximation)`

```
2, 4 -> 795341/48627125 (0.016355912466550306)
2, 10 -> 2689423743942044098153/22996713557917153515625 (0.11694817771107766)
2, 23 -> 38093904702297390785243708291056390518886454060947061/75091883268515350125426207425223147563269805908203125 (0.5072972343239854)
3, 3 -> 1/133225 (7.5060987051979735e-06)
3, 15 -> 99202120236895898424238531990273/29796146005797507000413918212890625 (0.0033293607910766013)
3, 23 -> 4770369978858741874704938828021312421544898229270601/375459416342576750627131037126115737816349029541015625 (0.01270542106874784)
3, 88 -> 121972658600365952270507870814168157581992420315979376776734831989281511796047744560525362056937843069780281314799508374037334481686749665057776557164805212647907376598926392555810192414444095707428833039241/238663638085694198987526661236008945231785263891283516149752738222327030518604865144748956653519802030443538582564040039437134064787503711547079611163210009542953054552383296282869196147657930850982666015625 (0.5110651106247305)
4, 5 -> 1821/17748900625 (1.0259790386313012e-07)
4, 25 -> 2485259613640935164402771922618780423376797142403469821/10004116148447957520459906484225353834116619892120361328125 (0.0002484237064787077)
5, 50 -> 786993779912104445948839077141385547220875807924661029087862889286553262259306606691973696493529913926889614561937/7306010813549515310358093277059651246342214174497508156711617142094873581852472030624097938198246993124485015869140625 (0.00010771867165219201)
10, 11 -> 801/8393800448639761033203125 (9.542757239717371e-23)
10, 20 -> 7563066516919731020375145315161/4825745614492126958810682272575693836212158203125 (1.5672327389589693e-18)
10, 100 -> 122483733913713880468912433840827432571103991156207938550769934255186675421169322116627610793923974214844245486313555179552213623490113886544747626665059355613885669915058701717890707367972476863138223808168550175885417452745887418265215709/1018100624231385241853189999481940942382873878399046008966742039665259133127558338726075853312698838815389196105495212915667272376736512436519973194623721779480597820765897548554160854805712082157001360774761962446621765820964355953037738800048828125 (1.2030611807765361e-10)
10, 200 -> 46037609834855282194444796809612644889409465037669687935667461523743071657580101605348193810323944369492022110911489191609021322290505098856358912879677731966113966723477854912238177976801306968267513131490721538703324306724303400725590188016199359187262098021797557231190080930654308244474302621083905460764730976861073112110503993354926967673128790398832479866320227003479651999296010679699346931041199162583292649095888379961533947862695990956213767291953359129132526574405705744727693754517/378333041587022747413582050553902956219347236460887942751654696440740074897712544982385679244606727641966213694207954095750881417642309033313110718881314425431789802709136766451022222829015561216923212248085160525409958950556460005591372098706995468877542448525403291516015085653857006548005361106043070914396018461580475651719152455730181412523297836008507156692430467118523245584181582255037664477857149762078637248959905010608686740872875726844702607085395469621591502118462813086807727813720703125 (1.21685406174776e-07)
```

Comment: Happy birthday (belated)!

Comment: Maybe add a couple of test cases for small numbers?

Comment: @LuisMendo I will add some more after I get a few hours of sleep :)

Comment: It's worth noting that the probability that people eat at a restaurant is probably not independent of whether it's their birthday, so the probability of five birthdays out of 50 people is probably higher than the Birthday Problem logic would suggest.

Comment: @GlenO Good point!

Comment: Is the input format in the same order? `(n, k) = (2, 4)` would be 0, but `(k, n) = (2, 4)` is ~0.016.

Comment: @miles Good catch, thanks! Not sure how I got those flipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ĠZL
365ṗÇ€<¬µS÷L
```

Extremely inefficient. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xKBaTAozNjXhuZfDh-KCrDzCrMK1U8O3TA&input=&args=Mg+Mg) (but keep **N** below **3**)

#### How it works

```
365ṗÇ€<¬µS÷L  Main link. Left argument: N. Right argument: K

365ṗ          Cartesian product; generate all lists of length N that consist of
              elements of [1, ..., 365].
    Ç€        Map the helper link over all generated lists. It returns the highest
              amount of people that share a single birthday.
      <       Compare each result with K.
       ¬      Negate.
        µS÷L  Take the mean by dividing the sum by the length.


ĠZL           Helper link. Argument: A (list of integers)

Ġ             Group the indices have identical values in A.
 Z            Zip; transpose rows with columns.
  L           Take the length of the result, thus counting columns.
```

Comment: "keep N below 3"... isn't that overly restrictive?

Comment: @Neil The solution is valid for all inputs, but the online interpreter won't be able to run inputs where N > 3, due to memory and time constraints.

Comment: @Mego I was just thinking that because it doesn't make much sense if you don't have `k > 1`, then given `k <= N`, if you then want to keep `N < 3`, that doesn't leave much choice for the values of `N` and `k` that you can try.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
365:Z^!tXM=s>~Ym
```

First input is `N`, second is `k`.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MzY1OlpeIXRYTT1zPn5ZbQ&input=Mgoy)

This is an enumeration-based approach, like [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82538/36398), so input numbers should be kept small due to memory limitations.

```
365:   % Vector [1 2 ... 365]
Z^     % Take N implicitly. Cartesian power. Gives a 2D array with each
       % "combination" on a row
!      % Transpose
t      % Duplicate
XM     % Mode (most frequent element) of each column
=      % Test for equality, element-wise with broadcast. For each column, gives
       % true for elements equal to that column's mode, false for the rest
s      % Sum of each column. Gives a row vector
>~     % Take k implicitly. True for elements equal or greater than k
Ym     % Mean of each column. Implicitly display
```

Comment: You outgolfed Dennis, good job.

Comment: @m654 Let's see when he wakes up :-D

Comment: Well, I woke up, but the best I managed was a tie. Jelly really needs a *mean* atom...

Comment: @Dennis I was thinking the same. Maybe a _mode_ atom too?

Answer (score 0):

## J, <s>41</s> 36 bytes

```
(+/%#)@(<:365&(#~>./@(#/.~)@#:i.@^))
```

Straight-forward approach similar to the others. Runs into memory issues at **n > 3**.

### Usage

Takes the value of `k` on the LHS and `n` on the RHS.

```
   f =: (+/%#)@(<:365&(#~>./@(#/.~)@#:i.@^))
   0 f 0
0
   0 f 1
1
   1 f 1
1
   0 f 2
1
   1 f 2
1
   2 f 2
0.00273973
   0 f 3
1
   1 f 3
1
   2 f 3
0.00820417
   3 f 3
7.5061e_6
```

On my pc, using an i7-4770k and the timer foreign `6!:2`, computing for **n = 3** requires about 25 seconds.

```
   timer =: 6!:2
   timer '2 f 3'
24.7893
   timer '3 f 3'
24.896
```

### Explanation

```
(+/%#)@(<:365&(#~>./@(#/.~)@#:i.@^)) Input: k on LHS, n on RHS
          365&                       The number 365
               #~                    Create n copies of 365
                                 ^   Calculate 365^n
                              i.@    The range [0, 1, ..., 365^n-1]
                            #:       Convert each value in the range to base-n and pad
                                     with zeroes to the right so that each has n digits
                     (#/.~)@         Find the size of each set of identical values
                 >./@                Find the max size of each
        <:                           Test each if greater than or equal to k
(+/%#)@                              Apply to the previous result
 +/                                  Find the sum of the values
    #                                Count the number of values
   %                                 Divide the sum by the count and return
```